# Need sflow, ceilometer or healthmon output files

Tags: openstack, monitoring, collectd, sflow

I am currently working on a mini-project in my college. It is a billing module for an openstack based private cloud. I need to read the usage from database which stores the amount of resources used and generate an invoice from them. For testing my code, I needed some sample output files of sflow, ceilometer or collectd generated by monitoring a cloud setup.

Anyone having such old files?